# A user replied to my comment with a racist remark, I flagged it, both our comments were deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments, abuse

The comments I'm asking about are no longer visible to normal users, but the question is here:

[How to Implement UDP Client Server File transfer in QT GUI in cpp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75047095/how-to-implement-udp-client-server-file-transfer-in-qt-gui-in-cpp?noredirect=1#comment132437957_75047095)

I was the first to comment on this vague question, and I said that it was not answerable without more details, such as why UDP was chosen, and whether the server side had already been written.

The question poster "Aviral Arpit" replied to my comment asking "Why do white people talk like this?" and a bit more text.

I flagged the comment as "It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse."  The comment was deleted, obviously.  But so was my comment.

Why would an appropriate and well-meaning comment like mine be deleted when I flag someone's racist reply to it?  Is it standard practice to delete entire comment chains just because someone in the chain said something inappropriate?

Comment: "Why would an appropriate and well-meaning comment like mine be deleted when I flag someone's racist reply to it?" - because your comment was flagged separately, and the responding mod decided that flag was valid. I'd assume it's your note on tutorial use, but no clue. Your comment for context to non-mod meta readers: " You'd have to provide a ton more detail to make this an answerable question. Do you already have the UDP server side written? If not, why even use UDP? Have you tried sending any data from your app to a basic server written from one of the many tutorials online? "

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: Thank you for copying my comment here, as even I am no longer able to see it.  I wonder if Aviral Arpit (the OP who posted the racist comment directed at me) was the one who flagged my comment.  I don't think that asking if someone has tried sending data from their app to an example server which can be found online is a reason to remove a comment, but if you or another moderator tells me that it is, I will certainly listen to that opinion.

Comment: I can neither confirm nor deny who flagged the comment, but it doesn't matter. Invalid flags get declined, valid flags don't. Barring mistakes, which do happen, but that's not the point. The point is that who cast it is irrelevant, as we don't treat flags differently based on who made the worst comment in a given comment section.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: Do you have any tips for how I should have written my comment to be not flag-worthy?  I didn't mean to imply that my comment shouldn't be deleted because the one who flagged it was abusive, but rather that perhaps they flagged it because they were angry.  I'm having a bit of a hard time seeing how my comment was so bad that it merited deletion.  Of course if you think it was deleted by mistake, perhaps you can revisit that or converse with the moderator who may have misclicked.

Comment: Regardless of whether the comment would have been deleted or not, it's always a good idea not to be too attached to the comments you make. They may indeed just be discarded for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I'm not going to argue for or against the deletion (or validity of the flag), because I don't want to. However, some mods have a low bar for when a tutorial recommendation message falls into rude. That doesn't necessarily make the response wrong, however. The use of "basic server" combined with "many tutorials online" can read as "have you even tried to follow a tutorial?" (this is down to interpretation, and the low bar), though "have you even  tried to follow a tutorial?"  is generally considered rude.

Comment: If you want to fully avoid that interpretation, one way to dodge it is tone down the tutorial nudging. One such rewrite could be "[...] Have you tried sending any data from your app to a server? There's plenty of good resources showing how you can implement a simple server to help with this" - or just cut the reference to tutorials and assume the reader can figure out what they need (or roughly where they can learn how) to implement a server on their own. Assuming an entire dedicated server is needed at all, and that it isn't a poorly explained problem where the server is an existing API

Comment: or otherwise has been provided in a way that's irrelevant to the core question. Not that there really is a core question. It's a combination of resource recommendations, broad, and unclear. No comment and just closing would've worked equally well as a result (and is the strategy for many people, largely as a result of comments like the one you got in response; though the actual type of rude in return varies). The various help pages do a relatively decent job at explaining the close reasons, making comments specific guidance regarding the closure. While often helpful, they're not required

Comment: and sadly, often disregarded. From observation, many questions get asked and then abandoned. This may happen when the question is closed, but no matter how constructive your guidance is, some questions are simply unrecoverable, and will never be rephrased (or even attempted rephrased) in a way that would warrant reopening

Comment: Your comment looks appropriate and necessary to me.

Comment: If the comment is for the sole purpose of informing the OP of changes their question needs that only the OP can provide, and the OP flags it as no longer needed, it existing no longer serves a purpose.

Comment: If the asker replies with insults, they’re clearly not going to care about your remarks or improve the question anyway. Just vote to close and move on.

Comment: I think your comment was fine. Was their comment inappropriate for Stack Overflow? I think so (without knowledge of “a bit more text”). But I don’t think it’s right to call it “racism.”

Comment: I would advise to keep the tone of comments as neutral as possible, and that includes avoiding overbearing terminology. Saying things like "You'd have to provide a ton more detail" fits the bill. "More information is needed" - nice and neutral and you can't misconstrue it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SO has always considered comments as less important than questions/answers, right or wrong. This means that your comments can get deleted by a moderator or migrated to chat, for a lot of different reasons. Sometimes the reasons are strange and you don't agree with the mod, but if all that happened is a lost comment, it's not worth losing sleep over.

---

As for what appears to be your comment, re-posted in this thread by @Zoe (a moderator):

> You'd have to provide a ton more detail to make this an answerable question. Do you already have the UDP server side written? If not, why even use UDP? Have you tried sending any data from your app to a basic server written from one of the many tutorials online?

I don't think there's any major problems with it, though "provide a ton more detail" may be considered unfriendly by some with too weak guts to be on the Internet in the first place. Similarly, recommending people to actually study the utter basics of something before attempting to use it, is frowned upon by some sensitive people.

(If you think this is unfriendly, for the love of kindness stay away from Reddit, Facebook, YouTube, etc., etc. Those kind of sensitive users who get offended by the sky being blue are unfortunately numerous.)

---

As for the racist comment, it is actually something that should be flagged under "harassment, bigotry and abuse". This would be a Code of Conduct violation and moderators will therefore also take disciplinary action against the user. Though that is done in a private context and you will never know what become of it, nor will the moderators comment on it.

So it is quite possible that both your comments were deleted for different reasons, but that some disciplinary action was taken against the user of the other comment.

---

Regarding the question you commented below, it is just completely non-salvageable. Since we get deadly tired of these kind of questions and the ever-declining quality of SO, it is very tempting to leave a comment about it... I do this all the time too. But it is often just best to downvote, close-vote and move on. Close as too broad in this specific case. Spend as little effort and energy on the question as possible. It is the person who asked it who needs to put in some effort.